# Named Queries in Doctrine

Tags: php, doctrine-orm

Does doctrine support named queries  ? How do I write named query inside an Entity Class like you do in JPA ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define a named query e.g. in the constructor of your *Table class, not the entity class:

```
$this->addNamedQuery('name', 'query or Doctrine_Query object');
```

Execute this query:

```
Doctrine_Core::getTable('Something')
  ->createNamedQuery('name')
  ->execute(array('params'));
```

The official documentation has more in depth examples: http://readthedocs.org/docs/doctrine/en/latest/en/manual/dql-doctrine-query-language.html#named-queries